# android maps "lagging" with few of marker on it

Tags: android, google-maps, optimization, markers

I create a new Project with the Google Maps Activity and have change only the method onMapReady to this:

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add 20 marker in Sydney and move the camera
    for (int x = 130; x < 150; x++)
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-34, x)).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

I have only 20 markers and I have ~10 fps when I'm moving on the map and markers are visible.
I'm testing on a Oneplus 3 and and a Samsung note S4.

Is there an event that compute I will have to rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like a bug on the google side. Whatever it fixed.